# Python defined function with range() inside doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I have a local excel file that consists of 100 URL's of the website that I want to visit and extract information from while looping through pages. To not replicate code after the NoSuchElementException error I have decided to create a user-defined function that would be called after the error occurs so it starts over with the next URL from list, but for reason the range() function doesn't work and after the error it keeps recrawling the same URL (range 0) over and over again.
Can someone explain me why it ignores the range() and just crawls one URL even though I have declared that the range is from 0 to 100? And how can I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/New folder/urls.xlsx')
crawl = df['url'].tolist()

def my_function():

    for i in range(0,100):
        
        driver.get(crawl[i])      
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
        
        while True:
            try:
                
                page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-track-name="Next"]').click()
                time.sleep(5)
                
                                         
            except NoSuchElementException:
            
                my_function()


my_function()
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the for loop except that it can be simplified to `for i in range(100):`. Your issue is that you have while loop that's never broken

Comment: While loop breaks after there are no pages left to navigate. Then it throws an error that I handle by restarting a function but the problem is that after the restart it visits the same URL (range 0) and navigates again

Comment: Nevermind - you were right, silly me. I've included the "break" statement and now it works! Thank you

Comment: I think, when you call `my_function` recursively, you are expecting  `i` to start with a value other than zero, taking up where its caller left off. If you want that, recode `my_function` to accept a starting value as a parameter with a default of zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/New folder/urls.xlsx')
crawl = df['url'].tolist()

def my_function():

    for i in range(0,100):
        
        driver.get(crawl[i])      
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
        
        while True:
            try:
                
                page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-track-name="Next"]').click()
                time.sleep(5)
                
                                         
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
                my_function()


my_function()
```